# Why is my fluid simulation mesh wireframe in solid view?

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, wireframe

I haven't used blender in a few years, and I've gone back to it to try fluid simulation, so I'm a bit of a noob...

I'm using 2.9, I've done my fluid simulation, but it's just showing as a mesh in the solid view.  Is this what it's supposed to look like in version 2.9? All the tutorials and on older versions I used the fluids was grey in solid view once the mesh was baked. Also why does it stick to itself like some kind of ooze instead of water?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sseUag-XJOKUFLwkbFl2hNw4v-gIzf6V/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Fluid sim in Blender seems to set the viewport display to Wire. Changing this back to solid will display your mesh as expected.

Object Data -> Viewport Display -> Display As

[image: Display as Location]

Answer (score 0):

2.9 is using MantaFlow which is different from older versions.

Make sure you changed the type to *modular*, and turn on the *resumable* setting. Once you're done, bake the fluid simulation. The baked animation will show as a halo particle. Then, check the *Mesh* option and bake the mesh. You can mess with the resolution for better result.